# LifetimeChanged event not firing when app goes background from Home button

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I have an issue with the LifeTimeChanged events on Android

code:

```
public class MyApp : Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxApplication
{
    ...

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        Mvx.Resolve<IMvxLifetime>().LifetimeChanged += OnLifetimeChanged;
    }


    private void OnLifetimeChanged(object sender, MvxLifetimeEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.LifetimeEvent)
        {
            case MvxLifetimeEvent.Deactivated:
            case MvxLifetimeEvent.Closing:
                MyMethod();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call MyMethod() always when my app goes into background.

When I use phone "Back" button - all Ok, but

When I use phone "Home" button - LifetimeChanged not firing.

It's a bug or I need to use something else?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source for the [`MvxAndroidLifetimeMonitor`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxAndroidLifeTimeMonitor.cs) it seems like events are not triggered for everything.

Only for `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy`. Hence, when pressing the home button. In most cases `OnPause` are called, maybe later `OnStop` then `OnDestroy` will get called, but it really depends.

You could implement your own `MvxAndroidLifetimeMonitor` if you want events or the other methods.

Just inherit from `MvxAndroidLifetimeMonitor` and in your `Setup` override `CreateLifetimeMonitor` and give it your own version of it.